# Android: Overflow icon event listener

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to add a listener to the action overflow menu button ( the three dots on the action bar )? 
I would like to add elements dynamically to the overflow menu, and I can't figure out how to do it.

Help please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to add a listener to the action overflow menu button

You don't.

> I would like to add elements dynamically to the overflow menu

You can try `invalidateOptionsMenu()` at the point when you know that you want different menu choices than what you had set up previously. However, I have heard reports that this may not affect the action bar.

If the "dynamic" aspect is based on fragments coming and going, have your fragments implement the option menu items (via overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`). Android will add and remove items based on the changing mix of fragments on the screen.